# How can I set a generic parameter in the moq setup?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, moq

I am trying to set up a mocked interface with a generic function using MOQ. the function has the following notation:

```
public interface IWizard
{
    bool Cast<TSpell>(TSpell spell)
        where TSpell : SpellBase, IComponents;
}
```

When I try to set the setup function, I can't seem to finish it in a straight forward manner. I keep getting the message that there are no implicit conversion possible. It contains the following text: 'There is no implicit reference conversion from 'SpellBase' to 'IComponents'.

```
var wizard = new Mock<IWizard>();
wizard
    .Setup(x => x.Cast(It.IsAny<SpellBase>())) // this line has an error
    .Returns(true);
```

What are my options, other than implementing a base class that implements both `SpellBase` and `IComponents`? Is this even possible?

EDIT1:
Ive tried to implement Piotr's approach, in in the following way:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test_JsonConvert_Performace()
    {
        var wizard = new Mock<IWizard>();
        wizard
            .Setup(x => x.Cast(It.IsAny<TestSpell>()))
            .Returns(true);


        var result = wizard.Object.Cast(new RealSpell());

        Assert.IsTrue(result);

    }


    public interface IWizard
    {
        bool Cast<TSpell>(TSpell spell)
            where TSpell : SpellBase, IComponents;
    }


    public abstract class SpellBase
    {
    }

    public interface IComponents
    {
    }

    public class TestSpell : SpellBase, IComponents
    {
    }

    public class RealSpell : SpellBase, IComponents
    {
    }
```

unfortunately my test fails.

Answer (score 0):

Fist Option:
You need to remove `IComponent` from `IWizard.Cast` constraints

```
public interface IWizard
{
    bool Cast<TSpell>(TSpell spell) where TSpell : SpellBase, IComponents;//wont compile

    bool Cast<TSpell>(TSpell spell) where TSpell : SpellBase; //will compile
}
```

Second Option: Create a class that inherits `SpellBase` and implements `IComponents`

```
public class ComponetsSpellBase:SpellBase, IComponents
{
    //IComponents Implementation
}


wizard.Setup(x => x.Cast(It.IsAny<ComponetsSpellBase>())).Returns(false);

public class FireSpell:ComponentSpellBase{}
```

Comment: the function Cast is missing the IComponents interface implementation of the generic class.

Comment: this won't compile for me

Comment: does your SpellBase implement IComponents?

Comment: It does not, and while doing that would solve my problem, it's not a course of action I can take at the moment

Answer (score 0):

You can create your mock in a generic method:

```
[TestMethod]
void Test()
{
    var wizard = MockObject<TestSpell>();
}

private Mock<IWizard> MockObject<T>() where T : SpellBase, IComponents
{
    var mock = new Mock<IWizard>();
    mock.Setup(pa => pa.Cast(It.IsAny<T>()))
        .Returns(true);
    return mock;
}

private class TestSpell : SpellBase, IComponents
{ }
```

`TestSpell` class is only required in your test project

Comment: unfortunately this will only work if I know the type I'm using, which I don't